# How to make div size to images

Tags: css

This is what I have

```
.headerpic {
width:100%;
background-image:URL("../images/layout/header.png");
background-size:cover;
}
```

My problem is, I want the height to size with the picture. I've tried.

```
height:100%;
```

But nothing, I'm stuck and don't know what to do.

Comment: What Mr.Alien said. You have to define the `height` and `width` to be able to get the background image to show. The background image cannot give the `div` a `width` and `height`.

Comment: That is true, but i think if you use background-size:contain and then make the div responsive that should do the trick?

Answer (score 1):

Try looking here:

http://www.sitepoint.com/css3-background-size-property/

could be you are looking for

```
background-size: contain;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do.

```
<img src="URL" width="100%" />
```

Duh...